# Texlive hangs when using tikzexternal

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, tikz-external

For a larger project I wanted to start using `tikzexternalize` to speed up repeated compilation runs. For that I wrote a small test file to check if everything is working correctly before introducing those changes in my main project. The test file includes the main code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzexternal}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepackage{siunitx}
%
\tikzexternalize
%te\tikzset{external/force remake}
%%\tikzset{external/only named=true}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htpb]
        \input{example.tikz}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

and the tikz-code in `example.tikz`:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[gray, thick] (-1,2) -- (2,-4);
    \draw[gray, thick] (-1,-1) -- (2,2);
    \filldraw[black] (0,0) circle (2pt) node[anchor=west] {Intersection point};
    
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Unfortunately, when compiling everything using `pdflatex --shell-escape test.tex` the compiler hangs, with the last output lines being

```
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgfplots/sys/pgflibrarypgfplots.surfshading.pgfsy
s-pdftex.def)))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotscolormap.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotscolor.code.tex)
```

I only can recover by killing the process of the compiler.
If I remove

```
\usepackage{tikzexternal}
\tikzexternalize
```

everything works, though. What is the issue here?

Comment: You're using it wrong. You either have `\usepackage{tikz}\usetikzlibary{external}\tikzexternalize` or `\usepackage{tikzexternal}` in your document. They are exclusive.

Comment: @HenriMenke: Yes, that solved it...